# How to add script tag codings in woocommerce add_action?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, woocommerce, whatsapp

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'whatsappdirect1', 35 );

function whatsappdirect1() {
    echo '[anchor-tag a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-whatsapp" href="javascript:window.location=waCurrentPage();">[img tag border="0" alt="W3Schools" src="http://sareechoice.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/whatsappicon.png" width="290" height="200"][anchor-tag-closed]';
}

[script]
waCurrentPage = function() {
  return encodeURI("whatsapp://send?phone=+9199999999&text=please let me know the price of the product in the link : " + 'http://' + window.location.hostname + window.location.pathname);
}
[/script]
```

I have made the following code, that allows mobile users to contact my support team on my website on my whatsapp, along with the link of the page. In the above `add_action` code I have put the codes, that will display my button, which has to be clicked on the woocommerce product page.

But now the problem is, that the script codes which does actual work of opening my whatsapp number with predefault link that allow users to send it to my number.

So how to insert that script code and also where to insert that? Is there any way, where I can keep both codes at one `add_action` function of woocommerce?

Comment: 1. Stop using excess points, you can't imagine how catastrophal it looks. 2. Anyways it would be highly useful to follow at least [these very basic rules](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291370/1783163).

Comment: See, how beautiful is your question now.

Answer (score 0):

try this below function

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'whatsappdirect1', 35 );

    function whatsappdirect1() {
        echo '<a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-whatsapp" href="javascript:window.location=waCurrentPage();"><img border="0" alt="W3Schools" src="http://sareechoice.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/whatsappicon.png" width="290" height="200"/></a>';
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    waCurrentPage = function() {
      return encodeURI("whatsapp://send?phone=+9199999999&text=please let me know the price of the product in the link : " + "http://" + window.location.hostname + window.location.pathname);
    }
    </script>';
    }
```

Comment: hi sheetal, it got solved,,thanks for the help ..actually a seperate script needs to be written in javascript file and then we can call that function from woocommerce codes...thanks for the help